# Visual studio treats incomplete arrays as zero-length arrays

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, c99

I have a struct that looks sort of like this:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int this;
    int that;
    int length;
    int info[];     // legal for last element of a struct 
} Foo;
```

When I compile it, I get an warning like this:

```
C4200 nonstandard extension used: zero-sized array in struct/union
```

Do I just live with the warning, or is there some property I can set to tell Visual Studio to use C-99?

Comment: Do not "live with" warnings. The size of the `struct` is unknown. If you don't know the size of the array, define that member as a pointer, and allocate memory as required.

Comment: I agree. I don't want to live with warnings, I want to fix them. However, the use of an incomplete array as the last element of a struct *is* supported in C-99. The use of zero-length arrays has been an extension in both GNU C and Windows C for many years. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: I should also add: this is older code that I'm in charge of supporting. I didn't write it and I can't change it.

Comment: No, MSVC does not support 0 length arrays. If you want a `struct` to overflow into allocated memory (from its last member), define the member string as `[1]` and let it overflow, into the correctly allocated memory.

Comment: Actually, it does, but as an extension. I can suppress the warning with a pragma, but I'd rather do this "right", which means changing the zero-length array (which is what the code originally was) to a flexible array member and then getting the compiler to accept C99 code.

Comment: Please cite which extension this is.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79wf64bc.aspx -- key text is "Declaration of a zero-sized array is a Microsoft extension"

Comment: Anyway, as I said, I don't want to use zero-length arrays, I want to use flexible arrays as supported in C99

Comment: MSVC is C99 nonconformity. (Apply to some)

Comment: Actually, within a `struct` the member `char z[]` is accepted by MSVC, as a zero-length member, so please accept my apologies.

Comment: BLUEPIXY, change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it. I was hoping there was some compiler flag I could set, but apparently not.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Why? This is a perfectly cromulent C99 feature, supported by Visual Studio. It just so happens that at this stage support for such features is sometimes accomnanied by spurios warnings.

Comment: @AnT perhpas you missed my later remark, apologising for the oversight, after I discovered that MSVC does accept an `array[]` as a `struct` member, but not as a plain variable. However it must the *last* member of the struct. Otherwise it's an error not a warning.

Comment: @Edward Falk: Firstly, despite what was stated by other people above, VS 2015 is C99 conformant (with maybe some remaining issues in the library). Secondly, the difference between zero-length array and flexible-array member is purely superficial. It would be prefectly conformant to implement flexible-array member as zero-length array, which is exactly what MSVC is doing. The only issue here is that they accompany it with that spurious warning.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Yes, precisely as required by C99. It must be the last member. Which immediately indicates that this is not some glitch, but rather a genuine attempt to implement C99 flexible-array member.

Comment: It is a non-standard extension in C++.  It compiles clean without a warning as long as you compile your source code as C.  Renaming the filename extension to .c is the simplest way.  And of course it is important to name the VS version you use, C99 compatibility is not complete until VS2015.

Comment: @Hans Passant: It should be noted that VS2015 *does* issue a warning *in pure C code* in Update 1 version, but produces no warning in Update 3 version (I have no Update 2 to test). This is apparently one of the changes made between Update 1 and Update 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 [almost] fully implements C99, but still treats all C99 features as *language extensions* (e.g. disabling language extensions disables C99 support as well). Some of these features trigger spurious warnings like the one you observed.

As long as C99 support remains in this semi-official "extension" status, just ignore/disable such warnings.

Note that VS2015 Update 3 no longer issues this warning for such C code.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are curious about the zero-length array or "flexible array" idioms, it's probably worth taking a minute to explain them. This idiom is as old as C itself.

Say you want to pass around a structure that consists of a header and a variable amount of data. It's not known until the structure is allocated how much data will need to be added to it.

The original idiom was to declare the structure like this:

```
/* Variation 1 */
struct mydata {
    int type;
    int datalen;
    char data[1];
};
```

Then suppose we wanted to return one of these objects:

```
struct mydata *
get_some_data()
{
    int len;
    struct mydata *rval;
    len = find_out_how_much_data();
    /* Allocate the struct AND enough extra space to hold the data */
    rval = malloc(sizeof(*rval) + len - 1);
    rval->datalen = len;
    read_data(&rval->data[0], len);
    return rval;
}
```

And a caller would access it like this:

```
void caller()
{
    struct mydata *foo = get_some_data();
    /* Start accessing foo->datalen bytes of data starting at
     * foo->data[0]
     */
    free(foo);     /* And free it all */
}
```

The point to this idiom is that the `char data[1]` declaration is a lie, since the data will surely be longer than that, but the C compiler doesn't do range checking, so everything is cool.

But notice the `len - 1` expression in the malloc. This is necessary because declaring data to have a length 1 introduces an off-by-one error into everything, and invites coders to make mistakes.

So both GNU and Microsoft added an extension to the language that allows you to declare an array of length zero:

```
/* Variation 2 */
struct mydata {
    int type;
    int datalen;
    char data[0];
};
```

While on the surface, this is nonsensical, it dovetails neatly with the idiom used here. Now we can simply do:

```
rval = malloc(sizeof(*rval) + len);
```

and the code is much cleaner.

C99 formalized this idiom by acknowledging that the length of the array is a lie, but the ability to have extra data at the end of the structure comes in very handy. So now you declare:

```
/* Variation C99 */
struct mydata {
    int type;
    int datalen;
    char data[];
};
```

and everything is coded up exactly as with the Gnu/Microsoft extension.

Unfortunately, it seems that Microsoft hasn't adopted C99 standards into their compiler, so no matter what you do, variations 2 and C99 will generate a warning. It looks like my only choices are to either live with the warning message or add a pragma to suppress it.

Linux users may amuse themselves by executing `gr -r '\[0\]' /usr/include` and seeing how *many* places use zero-length arrays. This is a very commonly used idiom.

As to my own issue: the struct I'm working with is actually part of an ioctl. The driver has already been written and I can't change it. The very most I can do is redefine the array from zero-length to flexible. Unfortunately, neither option makes the MSVC compiler happy.

Comment: "...and seeing how many places use zero-length arrays. This is a very commonly used idiom." It is a broken idiom that propagates due to laziness and/or incompetence of some Linux programmers (and GCC compiler catering to that laziness). The proper form of that idiom in pre-C99 language implies using `[1]` for the flexible member (as in your original example), not `[0]`.

Comment: Your `- 1` argument is not valid, since the alternative (proper) way to calculate the size in `[1]` variant would be `offsetof(mydata, data) + len`. See? No need to subtract that `1` anymore. Suprisingly enough, a significant number of so called "professional" programmers are blissfully unaware of such standard feature of the language as `offsetof` macro (to the point of trying to re-implement it manually, despite it being readily avaliable already).

Comment: Perhaps. I've never used that idiom myself. I've always just used something like `char *datap = &mydatap->data[0];`, or (in the case where `struct mydata` had no `data` element at all) `char *datap = ((char *)mydatap) + sizeof(*mydatap);`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in the last comment. My comment was referring specifically to the method of calculating the size for `malloc`: replace `sizeof(*rval) + len - 1` with `offsetof(mydata, data) + len` and there's no need to subtract `1` anymore regardless of how `data` member is declared (with `[]`, `[0]`, `[1]` or even `[1024]`). Meanwhile `char *datap = &mydatap->data[0]` is a completely different story that works in either case. I don't understand why you are mentioning it.

Comment: Meh. Doesn't matter. Bottom line is that I can't significantly change the code; I just want the warning to go away. I thought there might be a way to tell the compiler to use C99 standard.

Comment: As I said above, this warning is no longer produced for C code in VS 2015 Update 3. Microsoft fixed this issue already.

Comment: @AnT: The size-one form will invoke UB if code ever tries to access anything other than the first member.  The proper way the construct should have been handled would have been to allow what some pre-C89 compilers did, which is to treat zero-sized arrays as zero-byte allocations which are aligned for the appropriate type, and refrain from making any assumptions about the indices used to access them.  As it is, avoiding UB requires declaring an array large enough to accommodate the maximum index with which it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an array of undefined length (in your case in a struct) it is unknown how much memory needs to be allocated for it. When using variable 'info' it is therefore unknown where in the cache memory of the computer the program is writing or reading. This can make the program crash. Normally when you want to use an array of undefined length a pointer is used. Memory can be allocated for this pointer when it is known how large the array should be.

The compiler warns you about the problem I described above but lets you execute the code (at least it does in Microsoft Visual studio 2013).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: The code in the OP is a perfectly legitimate and well-known feature of C language. It is not an "array of undefined length". It is a C99 flexible-array member. And no, it cannot meake the program crash if you use it properly.

Comment: Also, you mention cache memory which is out of topic.